# How do you texture multiple objects with a single image?

Tags: texturing

I have a jigsaw puzzle with 4 pieces.  Each piece is a different object in the scene.  I have an image that I want to span across the top face of each jigsaw piece.  How do you texture multiple objects with a single image?

https://drive.brainsick.com/blender/texturing/multipleobjects/2x2puzzle.blend
https://drive.brainsick.com/blender/texturing/multipleobjects/apple.jpg

Looking for a technique that will scale across 1000+ piece puzzles.

Comment: Can't you simply UV unwrap each object onto the image? I mean, I know it would be hard, but, isn't that the simple way?

Comment: Use [built-in tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) to include images and [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to post files please, it's quite hard to open that link and it very likely can become obsolete. In your case you could use Object texture coordinates from adjacent node

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- #### USING TEXTURE ATLAS ADD ON

Instal an add on in *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
[image]

Select all objects in *Object mode* then press ***'+'*** button in the *Texture Atlas* panel.
[image]

Press *Start Manual Unwrap* button.
[image]

Go to the *Edit Mode*, select all meshes (<kbd>A</kbd>) and unwrap it as you like (in my case <kbd>U</kbd>-->*Project from View (Bounds)*), then press *Finish Manual Unwrap* button.
[image]

It will create one *UV map* for all the pieces.
[image]
[image]

- #### JOINING, UNWRAPPING, SEPARATING MESHES

*Remove doubles* for all your pieces (in *Edit Mode* press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles*) and join all objects in *Object Mode* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Unwrap it in *Edit mode*, then separate meshes with <kbd>P</kbd>-->*By Loose Parts*.
[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I had been trying the join/unwrap/separate technique myself.  I kept ending up with more objects than I started with; a single piece would become three - a top, bottom, and edge.  So I had dismissed it as non-viable.  Removing doubles before joining keeps the objects in tact when I later separate them again.

Comment: I am glad you like it :). About your issue- maybe you do it in a wrong order. At the beginning you have four separated pieces. You select one of them in *Object Mode*, go to *Edit Mode*, select all the vertices with *A*, then press *W*--> *Remove Doubles*. Then you repeat the same process for the other pieces. When you're done with it you join them, select all vertices again and finally separate.

Comment: It wasn't an order problem so much as I simply didn't know 'remove doubles' needed to be done.  I understand the technique now, thanks to your screencast / visual aids.